# How to confirm if motherboard is broken

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, boot-loop

This is in reference to my [other question.](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/35458/flashed-my-phone-without-rooting-and-now-it-doesnt-work)

My phone was not working so I showed it to service center guy and he said the motherboard is broken and needs to be replaced.

I can flash custom ROMs to the phone but they are not also booting up.

So I just want to confirm does that really mean my motherboard is broken and needs to be replaced?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it starts to boot (goes to the boot logo/animation) or Recovery/Download mode at least tries to load, then the motherboard is NOT damaged.

Your device is soft-bricked, and just needs to have a compatible ROM flashed, and your userdata erased for your device to be fully functional again.

The person is the service centre doesn't know what hey is talking about (I wouldn't trust those people - they just want your money).

Comment: To the downvoter: Comment please?